# IMU and Magnetometer Conventions in ROS: Sanity check

Tags: navigation, imu, robot-localization, magnetometer

I am trying to use a system that integrates one IMU and one Magnetometer for an outdoors vehicle, but I am struggling to fully understand some of the conventions used by ROS. I would like for this to be a sanity check to make sure that the assumptions I have are correct and to, hopefully, help any future users.

As far as I understand, ROS and `robot_localisation` (`r_l`) expects data to be in the **East-North-Up** (ENU) frame of reference, as shown in the following figure:

[image: ENU frame of reference]

Lets assume that our sensor is in a flat neutral position with the X axis pointing East. In this case the previous diagram indicates that:

- X points towards East
- Y points towards North
- Z points towards Up.

As for orientation, the sensor should indicate:

- roll = 0
- pitch = 0
- yaw = 0

From this neutral position the following motions should generate the specified information:

- If the sensor were to rotate from X to Y, that should generate a **positive** reading in yaw. From Y to X should generate a **negative** reading.
- If the sensors were to rotate from X to Z that should generate a **positive** reading in pitch. From Z to X should generate a **negative** reading.
- If the sensor were to rotate from Y to Z that should generate a **positive** reading in roll. From Z to Y should generate a **negative** reading.

As for the accelerometer, it should indicate:

- x = 0
- y = 0
- z = +9.81 m/s^2

And the following motions should register the specified information:

- If the sensor is displaced in the X axis (towards East) then it will register a +X acceleration.
- If the sensor is displaced in the Y axis (towards North) then it will register a +Y acceleration.
- If the sensor is displaced in the Z axis (towards UP) then it will register a +Z acceleration, This would be in addition to acceleration due to gravity, so if I accelerated at 1 m/s^2 straight up, the IMU should read +10.81 m/s^2. More information [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/83747).

As for the gyroscope, it should indicate:

- x = 0
- y = 0
- z = 0
- If the sensor were to rotate from X to Y, that should generate a **positive** reading in the Z axis. From Y to X should generate a **negative** reading.
- If the sensors were to rotate from X to Z that should generate a **positive** reading in the y components. From Z to X should generate a **negative** reading.
- If the sensor were to rotate from Y to Z that should generate a **positive** reading in the X component. From Z to Y should generate a **negative** reading.

As for the magnetometer.

Since it is pointing East, the sensor should read, in XYZ, (0, +0.00005, -z). The Z component is used to indicate the hemisphere, so negative is north hemisphere, while position is south hemisphere.

If the sensors was rotated so that X is now facing North, then the sensor should read, in XYZ, (+0.00005, 0, -z). Again, the Z component is used to indicate the hemisphere. More information [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/269030/imu-convention-for-robot_localization/).

Are these assumptions correct?

Thank you for your help!